# Convert decrypt file in php from vb.net

Tags: php, mysql, database, vb.net, mysqlbackup.net

How to Decrypt this file in php . using MySqlBackup.net library in vb.net project. help me to solve or provide valid solution.

```
Dim filePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\"
    Dim constring As String = connectionstring
    Dim file As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\backup.mdf"
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            Using mb As New MySqlBackup(cmd)
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                mb.ExportToFile(file)
                mb.EncryptDumpFile(file, filePath & Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) & ".mdf", Settings1.Default.password)
                My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(filePath & Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) & ".mdf", "http://localhost/reg/reg.php")
                ' My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(file)
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Please make sure to take the [tour] ans look at [ask] as we are not a code writting community but a helping community

Comment: well you haven't yet told us what the problem is, so it's quite hard to solve it. What issue are you facing? You've told us your requirement, you've shown us (some of) the code. So please fill in the gaps by telling us what's going wrong.

Comment: above code is vb.net in which decrypt file is generate. i wont to send same file to php and encrypt it. Need php code for encryption

Comment: That still isn't a question. That's a set of requirements. What problem are you facing in implementing your requirements? You've got some code. Presumably it doesn't work? It would help if you would explain what is happening when you try to use it.